# how do I add this list up without using Sum()

Tags: python, list, for-loop, integer, append

I want to add this up without using sum() but nothing has worked so far.

```
list = []
 
n = int(input("How mnay numbers do you want to input?: "))

for i in range(0, n):
    nums = int(input())
    list.append(nums)
```

Comment: Why do you need a list at all? Why not start a variable `total = 0`. Then in the loop add `nums` to it `total += nums`. After the loop `total` will hold your sum.

Comment: It's generally a bad idea to override builtins with variable names... Also, for a range loop, the default initial is 0, no point in adding that in.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a list.
Just use a variable, and keep adding as new numbers are entered

```py
n = int(input("How mnay numbers do you want to input?: "))
total_sum = 0

for i in range(n):
    # 'x += y' is the same as x = x+y
    total_sum += int(input())
```